# mongodb: UnknownError assertion src/mongo/db/server_options_helpers.cpp:355

Tags: mongodb

I was running mongodb without any issues until now. I don't really know what happened, as don't remember doing nothing weird. Still, now I get the following error when I try to launch the mongo server.

```
$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
2015-01-22T13:58:04.153+0100 Assertion failure getcwd(buffer, 1000) src/mongo/db/server_options_helpers.cpp 355
2015-01-22T13:58:04.169+0100 0x1017ae5aa 0x101759135 0x101745bf2 0x1015509ed 0x10132b7a3 0x100fd2be6 0x100fc5291 0x100fd60be 0x100fd68ae 0x100fc41eb 0x7fff8aff35c9
 0   mongod                              0x00000001017ae5aa _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE + 58
 1   mongod                              0x0000000101759135 _ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc + 453
 2   mongod                              0x0000000101745bf2 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 626
 3   mongod                              0x00000001015509ed _ZN5mongo18storeServerOptionsERKNS_17optionenvironment11EnvironmentERKNSt3__16vectorINS4_12basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEENS9_ISB_EEEE + 10237
 4   mongod                              0x000000010132b7a3 _ZN5mongo18storeMongodOptionsERKNS_17optionenvironment11EnvironmentERKNSt3__16vectorINS4_12basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEENS9_ISB_EEEE + 35
 5   mongod                              0x0000000100fd2be6 _ZN5mongo45_mongoInitializerFunction_MongodOptions_StoreEPNS_18InitializerContextE + 38
 6   mongod                              0x0000000100fc5291 _ZN5boost6detail8function17function_invoker1IPFN5mongo6StatusEPNS3_18InitializerContextEES4_S6_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferES6_ + 17
 7   mongod                              0x0000000100fd60be _ZNK5mongo11Initializer7executeERKNSt3__16vectorINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS6_IS8_EEEERKNS1_3mapIS8_S8_NS1_4lessIS8_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKS8_S8_EEEEEE + 270
 8   mongod                              0x0000000100fd68ae _ZN5mongo21runGlobalInitializersEiPKPKcS3_ + 526
 9   mongod                              0x0000000100fc41eb main + 331
 10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8aff35c9 start + 1
2015-01-22T13:58:04.177+0100 SEVERE: Failed global initialization: UnknownError assertion src/mongo/db/server_options_helpers.cpp:355
```

I've tried running `mongo --repair` too, but got the same error.

Comment: have you edited the conf file or your system reboots unexpectedly?

Comment: The only time I have seen something like this is when the database (or journal) path has disappeared or is in some way inaccessible.  You should have logs from the last successful start of the process - if you could post them it might help shed some light on when/why that happened.  I would verify that the folder you are using to store your MongoDB data is still there, accessible etc. and I would recommend backing up those data files as soon as possible in case something bad has happened to the volume

Comment: I also faced this weird error in mongo all of sudden, exiting my mongod. But closing the terminal and re-starting mongod worked fine. Weird.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is weird!

I'm on OSX, using iTerm where I've tried to run the above process. Once I've quite iTerm, and restarted it, the created shell could run the process without any problems.

It seems as the process could not stop previously. Before, I even tried running `mongo` to see if I can connect, but it failed.

Comment: This is weird!same here

Comment: Same problem and solution. Thanks!

Comment: That feeling when someone says "Have you tried rebooting?"  And you do... and it works.

Comment: same here; the mongod daemon crashed (because dbpath was in an external drive and i disconnected it). then i got this same error when trying to start it again. closing the shell and opening a new one solved the problem.

Comment: for my case, the problem came because i was in a shell with the working directory in an external drive, i runned mongod with dbpath to this working directory, accidentally i disconnected the external drive, and then i connected again the external drive and run mongod. the problem was that the shell was in a unstable state, as the shell still used that working directory but it was inaccessible. opening a new shell or executing `cd $(pwd)` before running mongod solved the issue.

Comment: in my case, i think that happened because mongod was running with a node app connected to it, and I deleted the app folder from the shell

Comment: I ran into this error when running `mongod` from a directory that had been removed when I did a `git reset`. Anyone finding this from a search, check on that.